# how to transfer the taken image using ngcordova file transfer plugin to my ftp

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ftp, ionic-framework

I am trying to upload image to my FTP.

what i have achived so far is in this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/w18GRwURfU9vHTbB9Uch)

my cordova file transfer looks like

```
$scope.upload =function(){

      var options = {
         fileKey: "file",
         fileName: "gopi",
         chunkedMode: false,
         mimeType: "image/jpeg",
         params : {'user_token':'Chandru@123', 'user_email':'wepopusers'} // directory represents remote directory,  fileName represents final remote file name
       };
       console.log(options);
      $cordovaFileTransfer.upload('ftp://308.3d8.myftpupload.com/',  MyService.getImgPath(), options)
        .then(function(result) {
          // Success!
          console.log(result);
          console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
          alert('ftp success');
        }, function(err) {
          // Error
          console.log(err);
          alert('ftp fail');
          console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }, function (progress) {
          // constant progress updates
          console.log(progress);
        });

    };
```

My response of my error function for cordova file looks like

> FileTransferError {code: 2, source: "file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.camera108827/cache/1462186990291.jpg", target: "ftp://308.3d8.myftpupload.com/", http_status: null, body: null…}body: nullcode: 2exception: nullhttp_status: nullsource: "file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.camera108827/cache/1462186990291.jpg"target: "ftp://308.3d8.myftpupload.com/"**proto**: Object

I have button **TakePicture** which will take the pic and show to the user and also I have a function to upload using cordovafiletransfer **$scope.upload** .

my ftp host is `ftp://308.3d8.myftpupload.com/` username and password is given in my coding in this i have a folder name called **gopi** where my image should store.

my path of the image taken is in imageURI parameter so i used services to set the path.

**steps I’m in confusion**

> 1) I am not able to understand the **var options** object in cordova file transfer plugin.
>
> 2) I am not getting any erro while remote debugging but i am only invoking my error funtion in my cordova file transfer.
>
> How can i update my taken image to FTP using IONIC

**UPDATE**

Thanks to gandhi's answer https://github.com/xfally/cordova-plugin-ftp some how i managed to connect to ftp without multipart.

but sill facing error in this

> $window.cordova.plugin.ftp.upload("/ping", "/gopi/ping", function(percent) {

i don't know what to in the first argument and second.

> $window.cordova.plugin.ftp.upload("/default.prop", "/gopi/default.prop", function(percent) {

the above line success fully posted to my ftp but i am not able to post my image which is stored in my ping variable.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ETGmdl4B0d5dlHWdJQ9m?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is available in the official documentation of file transfer plugin. The excerpt is as follow,

```
options: Optional parameters (Object). Valid keys:

fileKey: The name of the form element. Defaults to file. (DOMString)
fileName: The file name to use when saving the file on the server. Defaults to image.jpg. (DOMString)
httpMethod: The HTTP method to use - either PUT or POST. Defaults to POST. (DOMString)
mimeType: The mime type of the data to upload. Defaults to image/jpeg. (DOMString)
params: A set of optional key/value pairs to pass in the HTTP request. (Object, key/value - DOMString)
chunkedMode: Whether to upload the data in chunked streaming mode. Defaults to true. (Boolean)
headers: A map of header name/header values. Use an array to specify more than one value. On iOS, FireOS, and Android, if a header named Content-Type is present, multipart form data will NOT be used. (Object)
```

Check out this [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) for more info.

For your second question, try getting the error code in the error callback function and try to narrow down the problem.

**Update:** I guess ftp upload is not possible using file transfer plugin. The plugin definition itself states `"The FileTransfer object provides a way to upload files using an HTTP multi-part POST or PUT request, and to download files"`

You may have to look at this for [ftp client](https://github.com/macdonst/FtpClient) for ftp uploads.

Comment: You can see my **options** object in that i have give the my username and password for my FTP i am not sure what i have done in that is correct or not is it right or worng

Comment: @Gopi If you pass your credentials in params object, as per the documentation, its get passed along with http request. If you are not concerned about security vulnerability of exposing credentials in http request (although not reommended) you can get this values in server side using request params and authenticate. Else you should try passing them in request headers and add them to option object. Eg. var headers={'headerParam':'headerValue'};
options.headers = headers;

Comment: @Gopi I have tried out file transfer download and posted sample snippet on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629515/cordova-ios-video-tag-local-file-source/36889829#36889829  But personally not yet tried file upload

Comment: why do we need to store in locally in my case i have the image path and everything sorry for late reply. and also how it is doing

Comment: @Gandhi i am also struggling in this how to post an image to ftp

Comment: @Mohan could you be more specific posting your code and issue?

Comment: in the above question he says he can not upload the image into ftp and he is invoking always the error funtion while posting the take image.

Comment: in his plunkr he gave the ftp server and username and password also in order to post the image to ftp what should be used

Comment: here is the plunker what i have been doing so far i am also invoking the same error as above https://plnkr.co/edit/gJ1Db2AnyQ4NdYojS0Nk?p=preview

Comment: @MohanGopi i m not sure whether the question is edited recently or i overlooked the question because i dont think ftp upload is possible using file transfer plugin. The plugin definition states "The FileTransfer object provides a way to upload files using an HTTP multi-part POST or PUT request, and to download files"  You may have to look at this for ftp upload - https://github.com/macdonst/FtpClient Updated my answer. Please accept if helpful

Comment: @Gandhi i am not using Phonegape i am using ionic CLI only is it possible to send an image in that way helpe me

Comment: @MohanGopi You are using Ionic CLI. But the underlying ngfiletransfer plugin dont support ftp uploads. You may have to look at other plugin i sent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115581/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-gandhi).

Comment: @Gandhi please check the updaed question