# How to syncronize data between ionic 2 framework and FTP

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an app which can syncronize data between ionic 2 app and FTP server, I search around the web for more than 3 days and nothing to archive!

Someone can help me with any solution, link or keywork, please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic - Upload file to FTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233783/ionic-upload-file-to-ftp-server)

Comment: You can use `cordova-plugin-ftp` https://github.com/xfally/cordova-plugin-ftp Documentation example is angular specific so you might have some rough time but technically this should work

Comment: @e666, I already got this topic but you see, it is not a happy ending ^^

Comment: @AbhasTandon, thanks alot, but I still lost my mind to understand this clearly. Can you give me an example or a link which can make it easier. Thank you very much!